# Good Flex book for long time developers

Tags: apache-flex

Many Flex books seem to focus on people new to programming. E.g. I bought the book [Learning Flex 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517327) from Adobe Developer Library, which IMO contained to much noise, like explaining basic programming concepts etc.

Is there a good book that don't take the 'new to programming' approach?
I have been a developer for 10 years, and used languages like JavaScript, Java, Groovy, Ruby, C, PHP, Objective-C etc.
What I need most is to be familiar with the components and API.

Also, it would be nice if the book *doesn't* focus on using Flex Builder / Flash Builder. (I use IntelliJ IDEA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529857) to be really good, and like you, I'm no beginner, and wanted something for developers, and not for people totally new to it.

This book was just that.

Cheers

Comment: I agree - if you're a competent programmer you'll pick up Flex in no-time and what you really need is just a bunch of examples, which this book provides.

Comment: I bought Flex 3 Cookbook, but then there was another project to work on for a few months, so I didn't get to read it. Now I'm picking up the Flex project again, so I bought the follow-up; Flex 4 Cookbook. It's exactly what I looked for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the [Flexible Rails](http://www.manning.com/armstrong/) book was by far the most practical and detailed book out there.  Even if you don't know Ruby (you do though), this book is awesome.  You build a useful app for Flex and AIR, use Cairngorm (Adobe's supported Flex Application Framework, but people seem to enjoy using others like Mate and Swiz), connect to a backend with XML, JSON, and AMF, and build useful CMS-like interfaces, all using design patterns.

Then the [Actionscript 3 Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526955) is my next favorite.

But if there's one book you should get, get Flexible Rails.  I've browsed/read through most of the [Flex Books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=flex&x=0&y=0) at one point or another, and they're all either too fundamental, or just serve as references for cool tricks.

They came out with a new book [Hello Flex 4](http://www.manning.com/armstrong3/), but I haven't checked it out.  And the culmination of Flexible Rails is [Pomodo on Rails](http://github.com/dima/pomodo_on_rails) and [RestfulX](http://wiki.github.com/dima/restfulx/getting-started-with-restfulx-and-ruby-on-rails), both of which are open source on Github, and actively developed.  It doesn't get better than that in my opinion.

Best,
Lance

Answer (score 0):

[Programming Flex 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516215)

Explains very well all you need to know about the Flex SDK.